# How do I add a cart form to the product view?

Tags: views, 8, commerce

With [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) 8.x-2.0-beta5, I created some products and a view that lists all products with their variations.

I wanted to add the cart form to any variation, but I was not able to do so.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

To display an "add to cart" button on a **product's display** you need to:

1. Go to /admin/commerce/config/product-types/TYPE/edit/display
2. Make sure that Variations field is displayed
3. Select "Add to cart form"

**Views display:**

You simply need to add the "Product: Variations" field and set its display as "Add to cart form"

You of course you need to have the "Commerce Cart" module enabled :)

Not intuitive really. I might end up using Commerce Variation Add to Cart module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module [Commerce Variation Add to Cart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_variation_add_to_cart)

> How to use it?
>
> After you install the module go to product types
>   'admin/commerce/config/product-types' and click on the Edit button of
>   your product type. Now go to Manage display tab and choose 'Variation
>   add to cart form' as a formatter for Variations field. If you click on
>   the gear icon, you can see additional settings.

After that choose ***Product variation referenced from variations*** as a relationship in your view and add the field ***Product: Variations*** with the formatter ***Variation add to cart form***.

Also, see this thread https://www.drupal.org/node/2834812